# Does Grub format existing partitions?

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I am trying to install Arch on the same drive Win 10 is running on. When I use grub to create the needed partitions, it tells me that all existing partitions will be overwritten. All my partitions (including the Windows one) show up, but I fear that my data will be lost. Can you tell me weather or not it will be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub doesn't format anything, nor does it create partitions.  It's simply a bootloader.

Comment: I thought it would partition my harddrive with gdisk